# Can not compile Typescript files for Jest testing

Tags: typescript, jestjs, nestjs, supertest

When I tried to run npx jest to run my tests, jest is trying to read my Typescript files as Javascript. I have a NestJs application and I am trying to set up tests on a controller. I used the template from the Nestjs starter project.

I have a simple test file:

```
describe('PlaceController', () => {
  let appController: PlaceController;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const app: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      controllers: [PlaceController],
      providers: [PlaceService],
    }).compile();

    appController = app.get<PlaceController>(PlaceController);
    console.log(appController);
  });
});
```

In my jest.config.js, I specified ts-jest in my preset.

```
/** @type {import('ts-jest/dist/types').InitialOptionsTsJest} */
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  testMatch: ['**/**/*.spec.ts'],
  verbose: true,
  forceExit: true,
  clearMocks: true,
  resetMocks: true,
  restoreMocks: true,
  bail: false,
};
```

My tsconfig looks like this, I am not sure if I need to use a transform :

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "incremental": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": [
        "./client/app/*"
      ],
      "@assets/*": [
        "./client/assets/*"
      ],
      "@env/*": [
        "./client/environments/*"
      ],
      "@common/*": [
        "./common/*"
      ],
      "@server/*": [
        "./server/*"
      ]
    }
  },
}
```

All my jest test files it inside `/server/`. I have ts-jest installed. I have tried installing babel and configuring it using babel and creating a babel.config.js file. But still I keep getting this error

```
    SyntaxError: /Users/kaisinli/Desktop/helios/src/server/app/api/place/place.controller.spec.ts: Missing semicolon. (8:19)

       6 |
       7 | describe('PlaceController', () => {
    >  8 |   let appController: PlaceController;
         |                    ^
```

I'm sorry for all the long files! If anyone has an idea it's greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try configure Babel to work with Typescript, as it is essential for Jest to use it. Make sure you follow the instructions here, under "Using Babel" and "Using Typescript"
https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest. There are a lot of ways to set it up.